# With Redis cluster that has multiple shards, how can I use Queue in laravel?

Tags: laravel, redis, horizon

I am trying to implement "queue" with Laravel and Redis cluster (that has multiple shards).

But I found that Laravel Horizon doesn't work with Redis cluster with multiple shards:
https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/274#issuecomment-457218217

> Horizon does not work with Redis Cluster and likely never will. Even if it did work with Clusters, you wouldn't be taking advantage of the clustering because Lua operations can't operate on multiple shards in one operation. And, for Horizon to work properly, our Lua scripts have to perform operations on multiple keys in one atomic transaction.

I tried "hash tags" as per other questions in stackoverflow. By using hash tags, Laravel Horizon worked with Redis cluster that has **single shard**, but didn't work with Redis cluster that has **multiple shards**.

On the otherhand, how to configure for Redis cluster is mentioned in [Laravel's queues](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues).

So my question is:

1. Laravel 's queues work with Redis that has multiple shards?
2. If both of them didn't work with multiple sharded Redis, I think I should go with database driver with Laravel's queues even if it is not recommended for production. Is there any other option?

Comment: as the question is pretty old (I assume you already found a solution and implemented it), can I ask you how you tackled it and what was your solution?

Comment: On "horizon.php", I wrote`'use' => 'clusters.default',` for Horizon redis connection. Please note that I use predis, not phpredis.